# How can I bind a dynamic collection of questions with a dynamic collection of answers to a view model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, binding, radio-button

I have an app that is a multiple choice survey. The questions are loaded from a database and the answer choices are also loaded from a database. I want to bind the response to the model, but I'm not sure how to achieve this. Here is my ViewModel and View:

ViewModels:

```
 public class SurveyViewModel : SurveyViewModelBase
     {
         public IEnumerable<SectionViewModel> Sections { get; set; }
         public DemographicQuestionsModel DemographicQuestions { get; set; }
         public string Title { get; set; }
     }
 public class SectionViewModel
     {
        public string SectionTitle { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<QuestionAnswerViewModel> QAs { get; set; }
     }
 public class QuestionAnswerViewModel
     {
         public QuestionViewModel Question { get; set; }
         public AnswerViewModel SelectedAnswer { get; set; }
         public IEnumerable<QuestionAnswerViewModel> ChildQuestions { get; set; }
     }
 public class QuestionViewModel
     {
         public Guid Id { get; set; }
         public string Text { get; set; }
         public IEnumerable<AnswerViewModel> PossibleAnswers { get; set; }
         public int QuestionNumber { get; set; }
     }
  public class AnswerViewModel
     {
         public Guid Id { get; set; }
         public string AnswerText { get; set; }
     }
```

View:

```
 @using VSC.ViewModels
 @model VSC.ViewModels.SurveyViewModel
 @{
     SectionViewModel section = Model.Sections.FirstOrDefault();
 }
 <div class="row">
     <div class="sectionTitle">@(section.SectionTitle)</div>
 </div>
 <form action="/VSC/Survey">
     @foreach (var qa in section.QAs)
     {
         if (qa.Question.QuestionNumber == 0)
         {
             <div class="row question">
                 @qa.Question.Text
             </div>
         }
         else
         {
             if (qa.ChildQuestions != null)
             {
                 <div class="row question child-question @(qa.Question.QuestionNumber==null?"parent-question":"")">
                 </div>
             }
             else
             {
                 <div class="row question @(qa.Question.QuestionNumber==null?"parent-question":"")">
                     @qa.Question.QuestionNumber  @qa.Question.Text
                 </div>
             }
             <div class="row answers">
                 @foreach (var answer in qa.Question.PossibleAnswers)
                 {
                     <div class="answer">
                         @{
    
                             <div class="answer">
                                 <label>
                                     @answer.AnswerText
                                     @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>qa.SelectedAnswer, answer.Id)
                                 </label>
                             </div>
                             <div class="answer">
                                 <label>
    
                                 </label>
                             </div>
                         }
                     </div>
                 }
             </div>
         }
    
     }
     <input type="submit" value"Submit" />
 </form>
```

Naturally, this produces radio buttons with all the same names, so when I click on one for a given question, the previous questions radio button unchecks and the new question is now the only one with a selection.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: will you include the html generated by `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>qa.SelectedAnswer, answer.Id)`? The selected answer is currently not being bound to the model right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to specify the index in each ienumerable's input field. It is much better if you use `for loop`, but with your current code it could be done like this;

See the code below where to create index variables, then manually create a radio button with the indexes.

```
@foreach (var qa in section.QAs)
{
   // create the QA index
   int indexQA = 0;

   if (qa.Question.QuestionNumber == 0)
   {
      ...
   }
   else
   {
      ...
      <div class="row answers">
         @foreach (var answer in qa.Question.PossibleAnswers)
         {
            // create possible answers index
            int indexPA = 0;
 
            <div class="answer">
            @{
               <div class="answer">

                  // create label for, with index
                  <label for="QA[@indexQA]PA[@indexPA]">
                     @answer.AnswerText
                  </label>

                  // create radio button, with index
                  <input type="radio" id="QA[@indexQA]PA[@indexPA]" name="Sections[0].QAs[@indexQA].Question.SelectedAnswer.Id" data-index="QA[@indexQA]" class="possible-answer" value="@answer.Id">

               </div>
               <div class="answer">
                  <label>
                  </label>
               </div>
             }
             </div>

             // increment possible answers index
             indexPA++;
          }
       </div>
    }
    
    // increment QA index
    indexQA++;
}
```

Since the radio buttons have different `name` attributes, they will not be grouped with each other, so we need to make a script that unchecks the others.

```
@section scripts{
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
         $(".possible-answer").change(function(){
            var dataValue1 = $(this).data("index");
            
            // loop through all possible answers and check their data-index
            $(".possible-answer").each(function(){
               var dataValue2 = $(this).data("index");
               
               // if they have the same index, they belong to the same group, uncheck
               if(dataValue1 == dataValue2)
               {
                  $(this).prop("checked", false);
               }
            });
            
            // check the current clicked one
            $(this).prop("checked", true);
         });
      });
   </script>
}
```

Comment: My controller action looks like:  
  `public IActionResult Survey(SurveyViewModel viewModel)  `  
    `{if (viewModel == null)  `  
      `viewModel = new SurveyViewModel();  `  
    `if(viewModel.Sections==null)  `  
      `viewModel.Sections=new List<SectionViewModel>();  `  
`}`  
The model is not being bound.

Comment: @PJSlauta oh I thought you were trying to bind it to SurveyViewModel. I updated the code so you could bind it to Sections view model.

The updated code should give you 1 section with the selected answers